# Startup default heap size in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, heap-memory, glibc

ulimit -s shows the default *stack* size *limit*.

Is there a startup default *heap* size ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no

in 32-bit Linux, every process see a continuous 4GB space.  most of it isn't mapped to real RAM, but gets mapped on usage.

in 64-bit it's similar but much bigger.

Comment: 16TB for 64-bit, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Linux don't have a seperate kernel space (upper 1 or 2GB) like Windows?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes, but this is mapped on the same continous 4GB space each process sees.  IOW: each process sees a linear 4GB space, part of which is reserved for the kernel, and the rest is mostly free for whatever it wants.  The standard libraries create the heap on that space, so there's no need for a "default heap size", it's all usable.  Initially it's not backed by real RAM, but as soon as the process touches a new address, the OS gets notified and maps a RAM page there.

Answer (score 5):

`ulimit -s` is not the "default stack size". It's the stack size limit. You can also set all sorts of other limits with the `ulimit` command, and for each there is both a "soft" limit (which the application can override if it wants) and a "hard" limit (enforced by the OS, and cannot be unset once it's set unless you have root).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any distro that sets a heap limit by default.  You can check using "ulimit -a", and you or your sys admin can set one in /etc/security/{limits.conf,limits.d} so you may wish to check there to see if one is set.

Answer (score 0):

There is no heap limit, your application can allocate 3G vm(virtual memory) on a 32bit machine, but that doesn't mean the application has 3G physical memory available, depend on your kernel's OOM policy, it will be killed by kernel's OOM(Out-Of-Memory) manager according to how fast/much these memory are used.